# Magento 2 email sender differences

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail, contact-us

I'm using Magento 2.2.4 and I'm having some issues with email.  I posted a whole long thing about all my issues [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231774/magento-2-and-mail-configuration), but I've since narrowed down the scope of this.  I can't use SMTP extensions, such as [Magepal's SMTP](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app), GoDaddy blocks it.  I thought that was the reason why my transactional emails appear to come from `my-cpanel-user@bla-bla.secureserver.net`, and not our site domain.  However, if I use the Contact Us form (all Stock Magento), it shows as coming from Customer Service and has the right reply-to address.  So this works, but why are transactional emails not obeying the configuration of who to use as the sender?